# Cannot share YouTube videos or youtube links

Tags: facebook, video, youtube

I am having an issue and I don't know if it's with Facebook or with YouTube.
I have tried sharing quite a few videos. I've tried sharing through the YouTube "Facebook" button, as well as sharing the direct link, and the share link that is already provided. The issue is not due to the videos being private, or the "owner" opting out of embedding or sharing the video - because my husband can share the same videos just fine on his account.

Normally when I click on the big "F" for facebook icon on youtube, it works... but lately it says "An error occurred. Please try again later."
When I try to copy and paste the direct link or the already-provided link, it loads for a moment and then all it shares is the link itself with no description, thumbnail, or anything else.

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow, check the type of [questions](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/faq#questions) asked here. As per your query, it might happen sometimes when the Facebook is not able to get the data from the youtube, or would have some other issue. So when you want to post youtube video's link just add it in and wait for Facebook to process and display you info, if that doesn't comes retry. Same issue happens with me sometimes

Comment: No there´s a bug at youtube...playlists break also...but everytime we post on youtube-bugs you close the topic (as you did several times with mine) ...but youtube (jeffrey posnick et al) refer us to here for these issues..but he dont reply and you close the topic...please remove the youtube-api tag from this forum cause it doesn´t work...also tell youtube to not refer us to here